# Coupon Collector with infinitely many coupons

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are plenty of coupon collector problems on here, but I couldn't find any with infinitely many coupons.  Please let me know if this is a duplicate.

The problem is taken from these notes: http://statweb.stanford.edu/~adembo/stat-310a/lnotes.pdf
Exercise 2.1.9

The problem is as follows:

Suppose $\{\xi_k\}$ are i.i.d. positive integer valued r.v.'s with $\mathbb{P}[\xi_k = i] = p_i > 0$ for $i=1,2,\ldots$. Let $D_n = |\{ \xi_1,\ldots \xi_n \}|$ denote the number of distinct elements among the first $n$ elements.

(a) Show that $D_n \to \infty$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$

(b) Show that $$\frac{\mathbb{E}{D_n}}{n} \to 0 \text{ as  }n \to \infty$$

Hint: Recall that $(1-p)^n \ge 1 - np$ for any $p \in [0,1]$ and $n \ge 0$

I'm really not sure how to compute with the $D_n$. I tried writing $D_n$ as the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{A_k}$ where $A_k$ is the event that $\xi_k$ gives us a new element.  However, this didn't seem to help (at least I don't see how to make it help).  At this point in the book, we just covered the $L^2$ weak law of large numbers, but I also don't see how I would be able to apply it to this problem.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: For (a), you can show that Pr$(D_n \le K) < c^n$ for some constant $c<1$. Indeed, this bound is true conditioning on any possible set of $K$ coupons to which the sequence is confined; $c$ can be taken to be the sum of the largest $K$ probabilities $p_i$. For (b), use linearity of expectation to write $\Bbb E(D_n) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb E(D_{n,i})$, where $D_{n,i}$ equals $1$ if one of the first $n$ coupons is the $i$th coupon and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @GregMartin : Thanks a ton for a comment.  Do you think you could expand more on the bound you got for $Pr(D_n \le K)$.  I have tried to work it out, but I am getting stuck.